# Efficient way to insert large varbinary in MySQL?

Tags: c++, mysql, database-design, varbinary

What is the efficient way to insert large varbinary in MySQL using MySQL client library in C/C++.

I understand that I can store binary data by converting into a hex string

INSERT INTO Table(VarBinaryColumn) VALUES(0x1234)

However, this approach is quite inefficient as every-time I have to convert large binary data into a hex string before storing it. It also has an overhead of  reserving space (double the size) for the conversion, taking away any advantages VARBINARY has. This approach maybe fine using command-line but unnecessary when using C/C++.

We have requirement to store text and binary data and earlier we chose VARBINARY but this overhead is quite large for our application as we do have large number of such transactions.

**Edit:** Is there a way we can do it without hex conversation? For sure, the hex conversation is not an option for us however fast it maybe.

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: If you're using C++ the cost of converting to hex should be inconsequential unless you're dealing with terabytes of data. Have you tried it and seen how it performs? If you're storing small amounts of data a `VARBINARY` column is fine. For anything larger you'll need a `BLOB` or `LONGBLOB` column.

Comment: As I mentioned, conversation is not an option. It's a sub-optimal design and hence I am checking if there is way without converting to hex.

Comment: You can put binary data in a std::string and pass it using the c++ connector.  I believe std::string can contain `\0` characters, since the object contains both a data pointer and length.  I'm using this technique to store IP addresses and SHA1 hash values in `BINARY` and `VARBINARY` columns.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it directly in an SQL statement, but if you `prepare` a statement like `INSERT INTO FOO(BIN_COL) VALUES (?)` and then use `stmt->setString("your raw binary data \0 and more data", 36 )` it should work.

Comment: I would look at using *prepared statements* you should be able to pass in a raw array of bytes.

Comment: How much data are you dealing with here? How frequently is this routine being run? What sort of performance requirements do you have? You say "large" but I'm not sure what that means. Tens per second? C++ can convert to hex faster than it can fire stuff over a gigabit network port.

Comment: If you're doing many `inserts` of the same form, then you definitely want to use `prepare`d statements.  And I can imagine that passing the bind values as binary is faster than converting to hex, sending the hex, and having the MySQL server convert back to binary before inserting.

Comment: @DaveM Thanks Dave, looking into prepare statement.

Comment: @tadman as I mentioned repetitively, hex is not an option so no point dragging on that point. If you have suggestion without converting, please contribute.

Comment: @Yusuf Your comments about "reserving space" suggest to me this is a problem of perception more than performance. Please, do as Dave suggests. Try prepared statements. Just keep in mind that in the C++ Connector there is a whole *ton* of conversion going on. That's how this game is played. Don't let it freak you out.

Comment: Please, edit your question and include your insertion code or an approximation of it to keep this relevant then. The problems will become more apparent. I've asked for at least a ballpark idea of the performance requirements but so far you've said nothing. Each level of performance requires a different approach.

Comment: @DaveM prepare works as suggested by you. thanks a lot. Have something more of thread safety and STMT pool but will start a new thread on it. Thanks once again.

Comment: A "prepared" statement will have to scan and copy the entire string, possibly doubling the length due to escape characters being added.  This is potentially as costly as hex.

Comment: @RickJames as per mysql documentation, the prepared statement takes advantage of client/server binary protocol.

Comment: OK; that's more code that is manipulating the strings.  I don't know all the details involved in sending a string through multiple protocols, but I am sure that each byte is handled many times.  And the discussion is whether the number of times each byte is touched is N versus N+1 (or some other small difference).